# Understanding how to link css with html file on one page in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, stylesheet

So I'm completely new to the world of coding, and I'm trying to make my website with Wordpress. So far I have a theme and all I want to do is tweak a few things here and there, learning how to manage the code. Something which I cannot seem to understand, even though I have looked for answers everywhere, is how to code CSS with wordpress on a specific page. I discovered the CSS code for the entire theme, but I would never find my way round that. All I want to do is link an external CSS stylesheet to the HTML code. I already know about

"link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"

but this will not create a stylesheet out of thin air.

So my question is, this stylesheet, where will it appear if I have the right code? Will an extra sheet appear next to these ones?:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7me1x.png)

And if that's not possible, do I need to link to an external stylesheet in a program such as Notepad++? If that's the case, how do I do that?

I hope you understand my question and you will be able to help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are better off using this to declare your css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); echo '?' . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'); ?>"/>
```

and your file will go into your theme directory/ folder no need for additional folders just inside your theme create a style.css file

your css will be in a simmilar adress to the following

wordpress > wp-content > themes > theme-name > style.css

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out too

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a Child Theme first. You can do that by downloading Child Theme Wizard plugin. Then after you activate your new theme hover over Appearance tab which is going to open sub-menu with options. Click on editor, and then there will be Stylesheet style.css file to the right. Click on it and put your new styles there.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try this out

Comment: Ok, so I did this and started doing my new styles. However it does not seem to work. When I'm editing the HTML part of a certain page, do I need to link it to this new style? And if so, how? Or maybe it's the other way round and somehow the style has to be linked to the HTML (which I thought was done through the theme URL)

Comment: That style.css should be linked to all pages. Can you post the link? We need more info.